# Data transmission via CAN

Tags: can

I'm trying to send data out via CAN rather than using a serial port. I could output the following via serial port without a problem using FIFO buffer:

```
SERIAL_Send_String("ABCDEFGHI");
SERIAL_Send_String("JKLMNOPQRSTUV");
```

When I try to transmit the data via CAN, the CAN fails to transmit the second message because it's still busy with the first one. Is there a method I can use the queue the message and process when the previous message has been consumed?

Comment: I haven't used CAN personally but you'll probably need to include some details on the transceiver and platform / micro you're using to get much of an answer. Maybe also include the code you're trying to use at the moment.

Comment: Use CAN Tx Complete Interrupt.

Comment: If would be useful to say what processor this is running on, and if you are using any CAN libraries. It is hard to say what methods are available to you without this info. Bear in mind, although CAN is fast (up to 1 Mbps), each message has a maximum payload length of 8 bytes. It is usual to have hardware buffers so you don't need to wait for one message to go, although if you are trying to send lots of messages you would need software buffers as well. If you have no reciever, set up at the same baud rate, (and correct terminations) the transmitter will retry, which could block you.

Comment: What is on the other end? One reason that the msg is stuck in the queue is because the TX doesn't think it can transmit on the bus (be it something dominating the bus or the priority)

Answer (score 4):

CAN is not a direct replacement for a serial port.  Read the spec.

Data over a serial connection (COM port on PC systems, UART on microcontollers) is a bi-directional stream of bytes.  Some implementations use additional lines for flow control, but these are not generally controlled or accessible to the application layer.  There is basically no out of band signalling available to applications except in unusual implementations that use a few additional wires.

CAN, on the other hand, transmits *packets*.  Each packet is limited to 8 data bytes, and does contain out of band information accessible to applications.  Each packet contains either a 11 bit or 29 bit ID.  You can't just go sending bytes over CAN like you can over a serial port.  This is the same as you can't just send bytes over ethernet either.

As always, you have to **read the spec** before doing the design and then wondering why it doesn't work.